# How can I know the top dowloaded apps in my country

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, apple-store

How can I know the top downloaded apps (by category, say games, messaging, etc.) from the App store in my country?

How can I access Apple's Kids App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know the top downloaded apps (by category, say games, messaging, etc.) from the App store in my country?

Open the App Store app on your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch, navigate to the **Apps** tab and scroll down to access the section where you can see the overall **Top Free Apps** and **Top Paid Apps** as per the recent download statistics across all the categories.

[image: iOS App Store Top Paid and Top Free apps]

The data is shown for the country associated with your iTunes and App Store account and it differs between the App Stores from different countries.

You can further scroll down to access the **Top Categories** section and can tap on the **See All** link to see all the major app categories.

[image: iOS App Store Top Categories]

You can then tap to navigate into a desired category to view the Top Free Apps and the Top Paid Apps in that category. The below example shows Top Free and Top Paid apps from the Education category.

[image: iOS App Store Top Free and Top Paid apps in a category]

> How can I access Apple's Kid's App Store?

There is no separate Kids App Store, but **Kids** is available as one of the category within Top Categories. You can browse to the Kids category to see curated kid friendly apps.

[image: iOS App Store Kids category]